# How to set position of id on click using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have multiple paragraph with "id" that is working fine on click but i want to set position of para after click on left menu.

My code:-

```css
html{ scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
  .header{ background:#ccc; padding:50px; text-align:center; position:sticky; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%; z-index:1000;}
  .box{margin-bottom:25px;}
  .list{ position:fixed; top:150px; left:0px;}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  
  <div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">

 <div class="col-4">
 <ul class="list">
 <li><a href="#one">one</a></li>
 <li><a href="#two">two</a></li>
 <li><a href="#three">three</a></li>
 <li><a href="#four">four</a></li>
 <li><a href="#five">five</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="col-8">
 
 <div class="box">
 <h2 id="one">one</h2>
 <p>
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
 </p>
 </div>
 
 <div class="box">
 <h2 id="two">two</h2>
 <p>
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
 </p>
 </div>
 
  <div class="box">
 <h2 id="three">three</h2>
 <p>
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
 </p>
 </div> 
 
   <div class="box">
 <h2 id="four">four</h2>
 <p>
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
 </p>
 </div> 
 
    <div class="box">
 <h2 id="five">five</h2>
 <p>
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
 </p>
 </div> 
 
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

ThankYou!

Comment: What do you mean by "set position of para"? Sorry i'm not sure what you're asking here

Comment: when you click on left tab then para should be scroll as per clicked tab

Comment: Appreciate English might not be your first language, but I assume by "para" you mean paragraph? And it does scroll to the correct paragraph as you see when you run the code snippet above. Is the problem your sticky header sitting over the content? In which case give a top margin to the content

Comment: you are correct but how can i give top margin while click?

Comment: Just add it on CSS to begin with and you won't have to do it on click. So perhaps just add the margin to your `container` element

Comment: but it will also applied before click on left menu & i need only after click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to modify one of styles

```
html{ scroll-behavior: smooth; scroll-padding-top: 124px;}
```

Comment: Thank you @Epic Chen this is the exact what I wanted, now its working fine...

Comment: Glad to be of help. ^_^